# Bootstrap button doesn't appear correctly

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, django-templates

my button is currently like this:

[image]

As you guys can see from the picture above. The button has something strange at the rear. How can I fix this?

I am doing a mini project using Django and bootstraps. Thanks in advance!

Here are my HTML files.

base.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Nav Bar -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
          <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item active">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">TimeSheet <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Leave</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Disabled</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-nav">
          <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Login</a>
          <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Register</a>
        </div>
      </nav>

    {% if title %}
        <title>WorkTime - {{ title }}</title>
    {% else %}
        <title>WorkTime</title>
    {% endif %}
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        {% block content %}{% endblock content %}
    </div>


    <!-- JS, Popper.js, and jQuery -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

login.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %} 

{% block content %}
<form method="post" style="margin: 0 auto; width: 250px;">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form|crispy }}
    <div  class="text-center"> 
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary center-block">Login<button></button>
    </div>
</form>
{% endblock content %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a problem with the closing tag of button.

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary center-block">Login<button></button>
```

Remove `<button>` after **Login** text so final HTML of button should be

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary center-block">Login</button>
```

Comment: oh my god ! how dumb I am not seeing this. Thank you so much !